# JMeter request does not accept port number

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am using JMeter 3.0 and my HTTP Request looks as -

[image]

But port number is missing on result -

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: try specify protocol as "https" in the input field. left side to Method dropdown.

Comment: it is being taken as `https` using `HTTP Request Defaults` element

Comment: I just checked. yes, it is not adding port 443. But it is not the issue as HTTPS default port is 443 and seems working with simple google.com example for me (simulated the way you did but for google.com). what is the actual issue you are facing?

Comment: I was wondering that I should also see the port number on the request, that is - `https://91.202.50.245:443/xxx` and not just `https://91.202.50.245/xxx`

Comment: are you sure the missing port is causing the issue? because 443 may be optional to specify as HTTPS default port is 443. try with google.com for yourself.

Comment: found out that missing port is not the reason of error. If you post it as answer then I would accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing port is not the root cause of the issue as HTTPS default port is 443. If port is not specified, then it is assumed that for HTTPS, It will hit port 443.

Please check for the real issue.